# Invalid Content-Type: The retrieved media has an incorrect Content-Type

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am using twilio to try and send an MMS message. The twilio server needs my to send my png image so it can save it in their db and send me a unique Id to access that png.

I am testing this feature as a newbie.

I have tried sending the png image as an html image blob after getting in the frontend with a file input tag

Here is my frontend below to upload image

```
const manualMMSUpload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.target.files[0].name) {
            setUserMMS(e.target.files[0].name)
            const viewFile = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
            console.log(viewFile) // <-- shows blob:http://localhost:3000/06fe4f1a-06fb-4baf-a18f-7698ffd6e227
            handleInputChange({value: viewFile, name: "fileData"})   
        }
      }

<input 
          type="file" 
          onChange={(e) => manualMMSUpload(e)}
          accept=".gif, .png, .jpeg" 
          ref={InputFile}
          className="d-none" />
```

I am sending this blob to my backend which sends it to twilio with Content-Type: "image/png" <-- is this where I am wrong? How can I upload a file from a file input in frontend, and retain the ability to send an image with Content-Type: 'image/png'

Twilio is giving me an error Invalid Content-Type: The retrieved media has an incorrect Content-Type.

```
   const createMediaMMSResource = async (req, res) => {
            try {
            const { subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken, convoServiceSid} = req.user
            let mediaUrl
            let serviceSid
            console.log("req.body.uploadMMS.fileData", req.body.uploadMMS.fileData)
            
                await axios({
                    
                   url:`https://mcs.us1.twilio.com/v1/Services/${convoServiceSid}/Media`,
                    method:"POST",
                    data: req.body.uploadMMS.fileData,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'image/png',
                    },
                    auth: { username: subActServiceSid, password: subActAuthToken },
                    withCredentials: true
                    }).then(res => console.log(res))

           res.status(201).json({mediaObj})
           } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            }
        }
```

Here is the function that sends the data to the backend Node.js server

```
        export const attachMMS = (uploadMMS) => async (dispatch) => {
                console.log(uploadMMS)
                try {
                        dispatch({type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_REQUEST })
                        await axios({
                                url:"http://localhost:5000/mms",
                                method:"POST",
                                data: { uploadMMS },
                                withCredentials: true
                              }).then(res =>  dispatch({type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: res}))   


                } catch(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        dispatch({type: ATTACH_MMS_CREATE_FAIL,
                                payload:
                                error.message && error.response.data.message 
                                ? error.response.data.message :
                                error.message
                                })
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are sending an object URL to your back-end and not the contents of the file. Your `viewFile` variable is literally the string `blob:http://localhost:3000/06fe4f1a-06fb-4baf-a18f-7698ffd6e227` which means nothing to the backend or to Twilio.

Instead you should send the actual content of the file to your backend. You can get the content from the `File` object by calling the [`arrayBuffer()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer).

```js
    const manualMMSUpload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.target.files[0].name) {
            setUserMMS(e.target.files[0].name)
            const viewFile = e.target.files[0].arrayBuffer();
            handleInputChange({value: viewFile, name: "fileData"});
        }
      }
```

You will need to ensure you are sending the binary content of the file to your back-end correctly too, but you haven't shared the code for that.

Comment: Hey Philnash Thanks for helping me with this! I have added the function Im using to send the data to the backend. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: If you're using axios and Express, then I'd recommend reading through [this article to understand sending binary data from the front-end to your back-end](https://stackabuse.com/axios-multipart-form-data-sending-file-through-a-form-with-javascript/).